# Programmatic multi-select on the Silverlight DataGrid control

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

Is it possible to programmatically perform multi-select operations (eg. extend selection, remove selection) on the Silverlight 4 DataGrid control?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't notice it at first, but the SelectedItems collection on the DataGrid is directly editable. So you can add/remove things on that collection directly to change selection.